# Comparing inside of elements from 2 different arrays and gives actions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexing, compare

Is there any ways to compare index numbers from 2 different arrays?

Here's what I want to do:

```
if i[0] == k[0] {
    //give some action to k[0]
} else if i[1] == k[1] {
    // give some action to k[1]
}
```

...and so on.

I could've made each functions 0 to 4 to fix my problem like that, but then the code would've been too long and unreadable. I want to optimize my code as much as I can.

I wrote the code like this but this doesn't work what I want. All the `k` keeps getting action when I hover one of the box group.

[image]

And this is my code:

```
var i = $('#boxgroup').children()
var k = $('#panelgroup').children()
  $(i).each(function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {
      if($(i == k)){
         $(k).stop().animate({height: '500px'})}
    }, function(){
         $(k).stop().animate({height: '200px'})
    })
})
```

```css
  #boxgroup{
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    clear: both;
  }
  .box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    }
  .panelgroup {
    clear: both;
  }
  .panel {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    top: 400px;
    float: left;
  }
```

```html
<div id="boxgroup">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="panelgroup">
  <div class="panel">panel1</div>
  <div class="panel">panel2</div>
  <div class="panel">panel3</div>
  <div class="panel">panel4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Side note: `if($(i == k)){` will always branch into the body of the `if`, because `$(i == k)` will always be true. It evaluates `i == k`, yielding `true` or `false`, and then passes that into `$()`, which always returns an object. Objects are truthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want hovering over a child in `#boxgroup` to make the equivalent child in `#panelgroup` larger. If so, you don't need a series of `if`s, you just need the index of the element:

```
$('#boxgroup > *').hover(
    function() {
        var index = $(this).index(); // Returns its index within boxgroup
        $("#panelgroup > *:eq(" + index + ")").stop().animate({height: '500px'});
    },
    function() {
        var index = $(this).index(); // Returns its index within boxgroup
        $("#panelgroup > *:eq(" + index + ")").stop().animate({height: '200px'});
    }
);
```

Live Example:

```js
$('#boxgroup > *').hover(
    function() {
        var index = $(this).index(); // Returns its index within boxgroup
        $("#panelgroup > *:eq(" + index + ")").stop().animate({height: '500px'});
    },
    function() {
        var index = $(this).index(); // Returns its index within boxgroup
        $("#panelgroup > *:eq(" + index + ")").stop().animate({height: '200px'});
    }
);
```

```css
#boxgroup{
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    clear: both;
  }
  .box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    }
  .panelgroup {
    clear: both;
  }
  .panel {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    top: 400px;
    float: left;
  }
```

```html
<div id="boxgroup">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="panelgroup">
  <div class="panel">panel1</div>
  <div class="panel">panel2</div>
  <div class="panel">panel3</div>
  <div class="panel">panel4</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

See:

- [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)
- [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Comment: Thanks for answering. it helps a lot. I'll try to change it by myself

Comment: @calmwave - Nice one on adding the HTML and CSS! I've updated the answer, the solution does work with that setup.

Comment: @calmwave - Looking at the HTML, I should note that we can (but don't have to) replace `#boxgroup > *` with `.box` (or `#boxgroup > .box`) and `#panelgroup > *` with `.panel` (or `#panelgroup > .panel`). :-)

Comment: appreciated it! :))